# Fastest way to instantiate a pair of integer values in Kotlin to use as a fraction

Tags: performance, kotlin, fractions

#### Motivation

I need to instance fractions in my code without the rounding error of floating point values. Therefore, I decided to use a pair of integer values, one for numerator and the other one for denominator.

#### Question

I don't know what to use: `Pair<Int, Int`, `List<Int>` or `IntArray` (array and list of size 2)? What instance would be the fastest to create and dispose?

#### Measurements

I wrote this code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var b: Any
    val elapsedPair = measureNanoTime {
        for (i in 0..100000000) {
            b = Pair(-2, 1)
        }
    }
    println(elapsedPair)

    val elapsedList = measureNanoTime {
        for (i in 0..100000000) {
            b = listOf(-2, 1)
        }
    }
    println(elapsedList)

    val elapsedArray = measureNanoTime {
        for (i in 0..100000000) {
            b = intArrayOf(-2, 1)
        }
    }
    println(elapsedArray)
}
```

And got these results every time (not the exact numbers, but their order):

```
> 16338200
> 1340355300
> 6129200
```

It is clear that arrays are the fastest (because they are on stack) and lists are the slowest. But compiler could've used some optimizations for array, so these results aren't representative. Maybe there are some underlying optimizations for pair instantiation, that would make pair creation faster than array creation in most cases.

Comment: You need a benchmarking library to do an actual valid comparison. But an IntArray will definitely be the most efficient because it won’t have to wrap and unwrap the primitives. There’s a big performance penalty any time you mix inline classes (which includes all the ones corresponding to Java primitives) with generics.

Answer (score 3):

Use a data class:

```
data class Fraction(val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int)
```

It's really convenient to use:

```
val fraction = Fraction(2,7)
val (numerator, denominator) = fraction
```

And you can even add your own operators:

```
data class Fraction(val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int) {
    operator fun divide(divisor: Int) = Fraction(numerator, denominator * divisor)
}

val fraction = Fraction(2,7)
val divided = fraction / 3
```

As for performance, it's not a problem until you've proven it's a problem. As always with performance problems, you need to measure and be sure what the real underlying issue is, before sacrificing code readability.

Comment: Writing a `Rational` or `Fraction` class is a great way to learn about some Kotlin features (such as data classes, overriding `toString()` and `equals()` (and `hashCode()`), operator overloading, explicit property accessors, infix functions, implementing `Comparable` (and `Number`), etc.) _and_ get a really powerful and useful class at the end! And in very little code — almost all of that turns out to be one-liners. (The only complex bit worth doing is a greatest-common-denominator function, so you can store fractions in their lowest terms.)

Comment: As for now, I use type aliasing and add operators by using extension functions to add IntArray operators. But I agree that data class has a better readability.